# Getting an error message when trying to "Split Database"

Tags: ms-access, vba7

I am trying to split my dbs, but keep getting an error:

[image: dbs splitter message]

I don't have an append query. I have gone through every single object in the database, modules, tables, name it - there is no single "INSERT INTO" statement that I can see. I searched hidden and system objects too...

Any  idea?

Comment: Try manually splitting. Make copy of file, delete tables from one and non-tables from the other, set table links.

Comment: Be sure to run Compact & Repair before and after split.

Comment: This might be the remnant of a replicated table.

Comment: Many thanks. C&R is regularly done. God point, I will try splitting manually.

Comment: @Andre - indeed, I replicated one table. I will delete it and create one from scratch within the database, using the same settings. I hope that either that or manually splitting will work. Thank you!

Comment: Manual splitting worked. BE linked to FE and all works fine.

Many thanks!